# SQL Select, how to display numeric as money and reverse - numbers to positive

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a numeric column formatted that contains data like:

```
8547.22
-1254.22
```

For reasons beyond my control I need to present the results of a select in this format (this is one field of a much larger select statement) I can't add any new functions either.

```
-$8,547.22
$1,254.22
```

So to be clear I need to add money formatting ('$' and ',') and also reverse positive numbers to negative and vice versa.

I've tried the following which obviously doesn't work:

```
case
when a.principal_outstanding like '-%'
then '$' + (SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST(SUM(a.principal_outstanding) AS money)), 1), '.00', ''), LEN((REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST(SUM(a.principal_outstanding) AS money)), 1), '.00', '')))) - 1)
when a.principal_outstanding not like '-%'
then '-' + '$' + (REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST(SUM(a.principal_outstanding) AS money)), 1), '.00', '')) 
else 'ERROR2'
end as '<currentBalance>'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be formatting your data in the client, not your SQL Query.  And, to switch a negative to a positive (and vise-versa) multply by -1.

Comment: Thanks Tom, agreed I should be formatting in the client and not the query, but for reasons beyond my control I can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do this in your SQL query (and not the client):

```
SELECT  '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(TheValue * -1 AS MONEY), 1)
FROM    TheTable
```

**Edit:** Since you're using negative numbers, it gets even more ugly, but does the job.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN TheValue <= 0
             THEN '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(TheValue * -1 AS MONEY), 1)
             ELSE '-$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(TheValue AS MONEY), 1)
        END
FROM    TheTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom, this almost achieves what I need, but the positive numbers in the DB are now returned as $-8,547.22 not as -$8,547.22

Comment: @DanielL, it works now, but I really think you want to move this to your presentation layer, where it is built to do things like this.